# How to change v-model source in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have many Radio Button & I'm creating a Price List with VueJS. Every Radio Button has a value that contains a PRICE like 3000. I get the value of Radio Buttons that User has chosen them by v-model & this property get its value from VALUE Attribute. But the problem is that I need to when First Radio Button chooses, I should add the name of Radio Button like UPVC window or something like that in DB, But my VALUE Attribute has price & I should give all Radio Buttons different NAME Attributes & check them individuals to add a name in DB.

So I asked that Can I say v-model in VueJS to use another attribute like data-price & I use VALUE Attribute to detect the name of Radio Button ?

Maybe It is confusing, If need more detail Please tell me ...

Comment: It might help to show some sample HTML of your radio buttons (how you want them to render) along with what data you want to use when they are selected.

Comment: Can you say more details ?